# Scaling data lowers the quality of clustering

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

I'm experiencing a strange phenomenon. I have created an artifical dataset of only 2 columns filled with numbers:

[image]

If I run the k-means algorithm on it, I get the following partition:

[image]

This looks fine. Now, I scale the columns with StandardScaler and I obtain the following dataset:

[image]

But if I run the k-means algorithm on it, I get the following partition:

[image]

Now, it looks bad. How come? It is recommended to scale the numerical features before using them with k-means so I'm quite surprised by this result.

Here is the code to show the partition:

```
data = pd.read_csv("dataset_scaled.csv", sep = ",")
k_means = KMeans(n_clusters = 3)
k_means.fit(data)
partition =  k_means.labels_ + 1
colors = ["red", "green", "blue"]
ax = None
for i in range(1, 4):
    ax = d.iloc[partition == i].plot.scatter(x = 'a', y = 'b', color = colors[i - 1], legend = False, ax = ax)
```

Comment: As k-means is a heuristic working randomly, it would help if you do multiple evaluations on both and compare these. Maybe just use more starting-configs for k-means (n_init=10 is default). And it would be nice to see some code to exclude bugs. But normally preprocessing should help like you mentioned. But depending on your generation of the test-data, this normalization-step is not needed if variances are not that different (as means look the same too ; for b)

Comment: As you requested, I added the code used to show the partition. The scaling can be checked graphically. About running the algorithm several times, it appears that on well-separated datasets (like this one), the standard k-means algorithm always converge to the same solution. And it's what I notice on this dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your across-cluster variance is all in X, and within-cluster variance is mostly in Y, using the standardization technique reduces the quality. So don't assume a "best practise" will *always* be best.

This is a toy example, and real data will not look like this. Most likely, standardization *does* give more meaningful results.

Nevertheless, this demonstrates well that **blindly scaling your data**, nor blindly running clustering, will yield good results. You will always need to try different variants and *study* them.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.